# Passing array values in an HTTP request in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, http, request

What's the standard way of passing and processing an array in an HTTP request in .NET? I have a solution, but I don't know if it's the best approach.

Here's my solution:

```
<form action="myhandler.ashx" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="Aaron" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="Bobby" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="Jimmy" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="Kelly" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="Simon" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="TJ" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The ASHX handler receives the "user" parameter as a comma-delimited string. You can get the values easily by splitting the string:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string[] users = context.Request.Form["user"].Split(',');
    }
```

So, I already have an answer to my problem: assign multiple values to the same parameter name, assume the ASHX handler receives it as a comma-delimited string, and split the string. My question is whether or not this is how it's typically done in .NET.

What's the standard practice for this? Is there a simpler way to grab the multiple values than assuming that the value is comma-delimited and calling Split() on it? Is this how arrays are typically passed in .NET, or is XML used instead?

Does anyone have any insight on whether or not this is the best approach?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There isn't really a standard, but what you are using is the closest to it.

However, the values are actually *not* sent as a comma separated string, they are sent as separate values with the same name. The form data from your example will look like this:

```
user=Aaron&user=Bobby&user=Jimmy&user=Kelly&user=Simon&user=TJ
```

You can read the values as an array directly like this:

```
string[] users = context.Request.Form.GetValues("user");
```

If you use `Form["user"]` it will concatenate the values for you and you have to split them again. This is just a waste of time, and it also breaks if any of the values contains a comma.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the information I was looking for.

So the .NET Framework is smart enough to read HTTP parameter values of the same name as an array, and I have the option to get it as an array via GetValues() or as a comma-delimited string via indexing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using checkboxes or a multi-select list box, then a comma-separated set of values is what you get automatically from html. What you are doing is perfectly fine. If you generate an array in your javascript in some other way, you could generate comma-separated string and assign it to a hidden field, and use split() on the server in the same way. XML is certainly another option, but it seems to complex to me if all you want to do is pass a simple array of numbers or short strings. (Of course, if the string values you need to pass contain commas, this would screw up your simple plan.)

Comment: No, you don't get comma separated values from the html form. It's the `Request.Form` collection that concatenates the values if you ask for them as a single value.

Comment: Yes - you are correct, of course. Thanx for the clarification. I was referring to the way these values are typically accessed in asp.net and I did not explain the transformation the framework does for us.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and devised a new solution that uses JSON, that makes the request more succint and readable.

The get request parameters are given as `?users=['Joe','Simon','Carol']`

and in the server side, we use `Newtonsoft.Json` to convert the incoming string to a string array.

```
string result = context.Request.Form.GetValues("user");
string[] users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(result);
```