# post array of values to a http web service via ajax and read on asp.net web server

Tags: asp.net, ajax, arrays, http-post

I am just wondering how to do this:

I have a page which shows some tabular data. On each row there is a checkbox. The user selects two/more checkboxes; my web page must find the corresponding ids of the rows which are checked. I must send this to the http web service. (basically a *.ashx file). I have two questions:

1. how will I access this on web server
2. how will my web server know the total no. of items I've passed. Must I manually send this to the server as a http post parameter?
3. what if the data I am sending is more complex like a person object which has fields like FirstName, LastName, etc. ?

I know I can use a asp.net web service or a wcf service with exposes a datacontract. But what is the best way to handle this without the SOAP overhead; what if you are sending all this data via ajax as a normal http post?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing array values in an HTTP request in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776711/passing-array-values-in-an-http-request-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started might be worth investigating as a starting point.

In terms of your questions, the answers will *partly* depend on whether you are using MVC or WebForms. But in general:

1. If you use the above plugin, you will access it just like it was a normal form submit (post).
2. They will be populated into [Request.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx).
3. This shouldn't be a problem. Model binding on MVC should handle this fine, I am not 100% sure of the equivalent on WebForms (you could always do it manually).

My suggestion would be to ignore the AJAX requirement for now. Get it working with a standard form submit (POST). Then come back and integrate the above plugin to enable AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. How will I access this on web server

Using either postback (and a checkboxlist control), or handling POST yourself. GET wouldn't be appropriate for the task.

#### 2. How will my web server know the total no. of items I've passed. Must I manually send this to the server as a http post parameter?

It will send back the value of each checkbox you have on the form, which will give you the total.

#### 3. What if the data I am sending is more complex like a person object which has fields like FirstName, LastName, etc. ?

You could use Viewstate for this, or just re-assemble the objects on the server. Typically this means putting an ID in the checkbox value for the person each checkbox represents - you don't need to send back every piece of information about the object.

#### What is the best way to handle this without the SOAP overhead; what if you are sending all this data via ajax as a normal http post?

jQuery and JSON would be the best solution for this, if you want side step the built in ASP.NET ajax controls. As suggested, jQuery is the simplest Javascript library for the client side part of the task - you'll need to use [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)