# Pass array of string to controller

Tags: c#, http

I want to pass array of string to my controller. 
I pass my data from another c# code.

Here my get request :

```
String[] varList = new List<String> { "A", "B" }.ToArray();
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    await client.GetAsync(GetHttpSchema() + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host + "/AController/B?varA=" + varA + "&varB=" + varB + "&varList=" + varList);
}
```

And here my controller:

```
public partial class AController : BaseController
{
    public async Task B(string A, string B, String[] varList) { }
}
```

Now in debug i get the following value(Only one value) for varList : System.String[].....
Any suggestions?

Comment: No... The expected result i a new array with two values, A and B.

Comment: then why you adding a array to a string? `"&varList=" + varList`

Comment: so how i should pass my array?

Comment: Probably as a delimited string that you split at the other end

Comment: What format is expected?  Comma separated?  JSON?

Answer (score 1):

First off you can just create an array like this

```
string[] varList = new [] {"A", "B"}
```

Second you want to get the values of the array, but the `ToString` method for arrays is the default which just gives you the name of the type.  Instead you can use `string.Join`

```
string listOfValues = string.Join(",", varList);
```

That will give you a comma separated list of your values.  Or you might need to do something like the following to get "&varList=A$varList=B" based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776711/passing-array-values-in-an-http-request-in-net).

```
string listOfValues = "$varList=" + string.Join("&varList=", varList);
```

Personally I don't know what format you need those values in on your http request, so I'll leave that part up to you.

Comment: Thanks. About the array i know, i just wanted a quick change here in stack. I used your string.Join approach and this work great !!